# Filling na in a column in pandas from multiple columns conition

Tags: python, pandas

I would love to fill na in pandas dataframe where two columns in the dataframe both has on the same row.

```
A B C
2 3 5
Nan nan 7
4 7 9
Nan 4 9
12 5 8
Nan Nan 6
```

In the above dataframe,  I would love to replace just row where both column  A and B has Nan with "Not Available"

Thus:

```
A B C
2 3 5
Not available not available 7
4 7 9
Nan 4 9
12 5 8
Not available not available 6
```

I have tried multiple approach but I am getting undesirable result

Comment: Thanks. This masking approack works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If want test only `A` and `B` columns use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask test it missing value with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if both are match:

```
m = df[['A','B']].isna().all(axis=1)

df.loc[m, ['A','B']] = 'Not Available'
```

If need test any 2 columns first count number of missing values and is `2` use `fillna`:

```
m = df.isna().sum(axis=1).eq(1)

df = df.where(m, df.fillna('Not Available'))
print (df)
               A              B  C
0              2              3  5
1  Not Available  Not Available  7
2              4              7  9
3            NaN              4  9
4             12              5  8
5  Not Available  Not Available  6
```